# javascript error coming on getaway system

Tags: javascript

I have done payment gateway system, it was working fine but today i am getting error, can you help me on below error, i have post function also what i have done. I need help to fix this issue

Visit https://www.koamastravel.com/payments/pay.php?payment=735d8d17999518e7bf777598a515c727&mode=SafIM

```
 function GenerateSignature(){
    var PaymentSelected = document.getElementsByName('PaymentSelected')[0].value;
    var xval = PaymentSelected.split("|");
    var PaymentID = xval[0];
    var CustomerID = xval[1];
    var CustomerReservationID = xval[2];
    var QuoteID = xval[3];
    var PaymentAmount = xval[4];


    var PurchaseCurrency = document.getElementsByName('PurchaseCurrency')[0].value;
    var url = 'ajax-pay.php?GenerateSignature=Yes&QuoteID='+QuoteID+'&CustomerReservationID='+CustomerReservationID+'&CustomerID='+CustomerID+'&PaymentID='+PaymentID+'&PaymentAmount='+PaymentAmount+'&PurchaseCurrency='+PurchaseCurrency;
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null){
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=GenerateSignatureOut; 
    xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function GenerateSignatureOut(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
        var mytool_array=response.split("<ajax>");
        var Status = mytool_array[0];
        var OrderID = mytool_array[1];
        var PurchaseAmt = mytool_array[2];
        var Signature = mytool_array[3];
        var MerID = mytool_array[4];
        var AcqID = mytool_array[5];
        if (Status=='Good'){
            document.getElementsByName('OrderID')[0].value = OrderID;
            document.getElementsByName('PurchaseAmt')[0].value = PurchaseAmt;
            document.getElementsByName('Signature')[0].value = Signature;
            document.getElementsByName('MerID')[0].value = MerID;
            document.getElementsByName('AcqID')[0].value = AcqID;
            document.getElementsByName('saveratebut')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }else{
            document.getElementsByName('OrderID')[0].value = 'Error';
            document.getElementsByName('PurchaseAmt')[0].value = 'Error';
            document.getElementsByName('Signature')[0].value = 'Error';
            document.getElementsByName('MerID')[0].value = 'Error';
            document.getElementsByName('AcqID')[0].value = 'Error';
            document.getElementsByName('saveratebut')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            alert('We are sorry, there is an error. Please contact admin of this site.');
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
} 

function PaymentFormValidator(theForm){
    var Error='';
    if(!document.getElementsByName('checkbox')[0].checked){
        Error='You Must Agree to the Booking & Cancellation Policy and Privacy Policy of <?=$WEBSITE_NAME?>.';
    }
    if (Error){
        alert(Error);
        return (false);
    }else{
        return (true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: You should use `<script>` tags not `<pre>` tags...

Comment: I am using <script> not <pre>

Comment: you go to this url and select payment 
https://www.koamastravel.com/payments/pay.php?payment=735d8d17999518e7bf777598a515c727&mode=SafIM

so you will get this alert
alert('We are sorry, there is an error. Please contact admin of this site.')

i want to know how to trace how this error is coming

Comment: what is **ajax-pay.php**? is it backend api url

Comment: you are getting **Error<ajax><ajax>000000001000<ajax><ajax>9809680382<ajax>407387<ajax>** response from **ajax-pay.php** call.

Comment: That unexpected token. I notice you construct that url variable by concatinating strings to variables. What if those variables contain unexpected characters. Maybe that url should be [urlencoded](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)?

Comment: If you're adding snippets of code to the question on SO use {} button. It will indent code with 4 spaces and that's enough. You don't need to wrap code in `<pre>` tags. It will also syntax highlight the code so it's easier to read.